# Using SPDatasource with a dropdownlist -- Need to dynamically pass SP List

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

I am creating a custom webpart for SP 2010. I need to use the SPDataSource control with a dropdownlist. 
I got this to work perfectly if the SP list is hardcoded in the  node, but what if I dont know which list needs to be used and this information is passed by the user via the "Edit Web Part" of the custom web part?

Here's what works:

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" ID="FolderNameDataSource"  
DataSourceMode="List"     SelectCommand="<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'      
Ascending='true' /></OrderBy></Query>">
<SelectParameters> 
 <asp:Parameter Name="ListName" DefaultValue="Forms Library" /> 
</SelectParameters>

</SharePoint:SPDataSource>  
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlFolderNames" CssClass="title"  
DataSourceID="FolderNameDataSource" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Title" 
AutoPostBack ="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

DefaultValue is where the SP list is passed. How can I do all of this programmatically? I capture the user entered listname like this:

```
_listname = this.WebPart.FolderNameValue;
```

Now how can I pass this to the parameter?

Thanks, 
Ninel

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the declarative binding, use the code behind
- Create a **WebPart property** for List Name
- Validate the ListName entered (Type of list , existence ..etc)
- If valid, bind the DropDown on runtime and make it visible.

Comment: Hi Vamsi,                                               Thanks for the response, but I was already able to create the webpart property. I'm stuck at creating the SPDatasource and dropdownlist on runtime.                                                     Thanks,Ninel

Comment: Creating SPDatasource and dropdownlist on runtime is possible but needs extra coding for state mgmt. So, I would suggest declare them declarative (I assume you are using ascx file) and then configure them on the runtime.

Comment: I got it working sort of...                                                        I need to use the DataSourceID from SPDataSource in the delcaration of the dropdown. Can you please help me with that?